# Regarding question https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174476/sql-trigger-updating-count

Tags: sql-server-2014

I really appreciate your  help with [my previous question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174476/sql-trigger-updating-count). I have one more:

If I were to add a "Customer" Column, where each customer can have one or many cases. So, "CustomerID" would be a foreign key for the Cases table. I would like for the CustomerID to start with 100 and increment by 100 each time a new customer is added. How would I have the table that outputed from your join statement (shown below) include a Customer Column? So Customer 100 could have cases 1, 5, 7 while customer 200 could have cases 2,3, and 4. Do you see what i'm saying? It's completely random, I just want the Customer Column to match with its corresponding cases. Thanks so much for your help, I am new to SQL so all your help is greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Cases c
    INNER JOIN dbo.Evidence e ON c.CaseID = e.CaseID
```

Comment: Please do remember to tag your question with the DBMS you're using. Also, note that different people may respond to different questions, so it's a good idea to include any necessary information when submitting a follow-up question like this. I've added a link to the question you reference in the title - you may want to edit the title so it better reflects the question (didn't feel comfortable trying to do that for you, in this case).

Comment: Using SQLServer2014

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a `Customer` table. Include a `CustomerID` columns, as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
       CustomerID int IDENTITY(100,100) NOT NULL,
       CONSTRAINT PK_Customer PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID),
       ...
```

This would create the `Customer` table, set up `CustomerID` to start with 100 (first argument to `IDENTITY`), and to increment by 100 (second argument to `IDENTITY`). this would also make `CustomerID` the primary key for your table; that's not an absolute requirement, but most of the time a table with an `IDENTITY` column will use that column as the primary key.

Then, you would need to populate `Customer` with your data.

Next, you would add the `CustomerID` column to the `Cases` table. This can be done with the `ALTER TABLE` command, if you want to keep your current `Evidence` and `Cases` data intact:

```
ALTER TABLE Cases
  ADD CustomerID int
;

ALTER TABLE Cases
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Cases_Customer
      FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID)
      REFERENCES Customer(CustomerID)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
;
```

NOTE: With these options set, deleting a `Customer` row will delete all rows in `Cases` linked to that `Customer`. You may want a different option, like `ON DELETE SET NULL`, which (logically enough) would reset the `CustomerID` values in `Cases` to `NULL`, where they originally matched the deleted row(s).

Next, you update existing cases with the appropriate `CustomerID`.

Then, your query would look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Cases c
    INNER JOIN dbo.Evidence e ON c.CaseID = e.CaseID
    LEFT  JOIN dbo.Customer cu ON c.CustomerID = cu.CustomerID
;
```

By using a LEFT JOIN, we make sure all the `Cases` and `Evidence` rows you originally saw are still returned, even if they are not yet tied to a `Customer` row.

NOTE 2: If all `Cases` must have a valid `CustomerID`, then you'd want to use `ALTER TABLE` again once you've gotten the `CustomerID` values in `Cases` filled in, to make the `CustomerID` column mandatory:

```
ALTER TABLE Cases
  ALTER COLUMN CustomerID int NOT NULL
;
```

Comment: Thank you, would I still use the original stored procedures as well? Or do I need to add a stored procedure for the customer table?

Comment: You would have to modify the procedures for the `Cases` table so you could set the `CustomerID` field. You would not *have* to create stored procedures for `Customer`; however, for the sake of consistency, you might *want* to do so. Controlling all inserts, updates, and deletes by your application with stored procedures is a good practice, as it makes security a bit simpler (you can prevent users from inserting, updating, or deleting records via direct SQL commands while still allowing them to do so via the stored procedures).